# Django Aggregation: highest sum in categories

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hy Guys

I was wondering how I can get the highest sum of one category.

So i have a model with my categories and a model with my costs which contains a cost category.

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class CostCat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)


class Cost(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    cost_category = models.ForeignKey(CostCat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,null=True, blank=True)
```

The result should be that I can show the category with  the highest sum of costs.

I have been stuck on that for hours now. The closest i got was with my tests as shown below.

I can print out all the sums and its respective category but now I now need to find out how to get the category and the value of the highest sum. And i'm really in a spiral right now.

**views.py**

```
def metrics(request):

    tests = CostCat.objects.annotate(sum=Sum('cost__amount'))

    for test in tests:

        print(test, test.sum)

    return render(request, 'metrics.html', "topcostcat":test, "topcostcatsum":test.sum )
```

Much appreciated if you could me a bit out!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by the cost and obtain the last one, so:

```
def metrics(request):
    topcat = CostCat.objects.annotate(sum=Sum('cost__amount')).latest('sum')
    return render(request, 'metrics.html', {'topcat': topcat})
```

or if it is possible that there are categories without a `Cost`, you can use [**`nulls_last=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.desc):

```
from django.db.models import F

def metrics(request):
    topcat = CostCat.objects.annotate(sum=Sum('cost__amount')).earliest(
        F('sum').desc(nulls_last=True)
    )
    return render(request, 'metrics.html', {'topcat': topcat})
```

Comment: OMG that I did not think of that. Thank you! That took me way to long.

To be completely answer my question i did:


`def metrics(request):
    topcat = CostCat.objects.annotate(sum=Sum('cost__amount')).latest('sum')
    return render(request, 'metrics.html', {'topcat': topcat, 'topcatsum': topcat.sum})`

Comment: follow up question on that. I see I now recieve categories which don't have a cost assigned to them in my result. But I should see the highest value. Any idea?

Comment: @Gerhand: then you can probably fix this with `nulls_last=True`: see edit. The ordering of `NULL` is database dependent, by using `nulls_last`, you ensure that the nulls are written as last item.